# GET min over multiple columns

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Can someone give me some advice on how I can get the min of values over multiple colums?
I'd like to do this without using a subquery if possible.

Thanks in advance!

something like the function 'least'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`least` seems to be exactly what you need:

```
SELECT LEAST(MIN(col1), MIN(col2), MIN(col3)) AS minium_of_three_columns
FROM   my_table
```